# Is it possible to track sublistChanged events in client script 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, sublist, clientscript

I want to know, is that possible that we can track whether the sublist button user has pressed is Add/Insert/Delete, after populating all of the mandatory sublist fields, under `sublistChanged` entry point of client script 2.0. (For e.g.):

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define([], function() {


    function sublistChanged(c) {
        if(c.mode == "add"){
            //Some Code
        }
        else if(c.mode == "insert"){
            //Some Code
        }
        else if(c.mode == "delete"){
            //Some Code
        }
    }

    return {
        sublistChanged: sublistChanged
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are more specific entry points like validateDelete, validateInsert and validateLine.

Comment: Dear Brian, thanks for your comment! yes that's the only way to make it specific. 
I searched for that alot and end up using validateLine entry point to make the script run specifically when the user will press ADD button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian said in a comment, the API provides three other entry points that trigger for those cases:

- `validateLine` for line additions
- `validateInsert` for line insertions
- `validateDelete` for line deletions

These each require a boolean return value to allow or deny the operation.

Comment: Dear Adam, thanks for the answer, yes you are right we can control execution of some sublist actions like(ADD, REMOVE & INSERT) of user by returning TRUE/ FALSE in these entry points.